# Equinox.log for Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, equinox

I'm trying to set up Juno 4.2 M6, Eclipse Tester version from Developer Builds at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php.  I need to add the Redmine Mylyn (https://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/) but it needs org.eclipse.equinox.log 1.2.0.

I thought I had found it by searching Juno install site and getting it from EclipseRT Target Platform Components > Object Teams Equinox Integration. But, nope, that's not the right place.

Where can I find org.eclipse.equinox.log 1.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the update site for Eclipse 3.4. Are you sure that this is the version you need?

`.eclipse.equinox.log` is in the eclipse update sites (which contains the equinox SDK as well as the eclipse SDK).

- 1.1.0 is in 3.4.x (Ganymede) - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4
- 1.2.0 is in 3.5 (Galileo) - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4

Comment: Are you sure?  I can't seem to find that in Galileo even when I try to search for "equinox.log".  And anyway, it's not Galileo or Ganymede I'm using, but Juno.  Juno is the next version after Indigo - it's the Developer build.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to respond, but anyway...I needed the same package and you can get it 2 ways:

Directly from here:

[org.eclipse.equinox.log version 1.0.100](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/equinox/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/download.php?dropFile=org.eclipse.equinox.log_1.0.100.v20070226.jar)

Or you can check it out from the dev.eclipse.org repos:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.equinox/compendium/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.log/?root=RT_Project

Just go to CVS perspective, if you are using Juno you should already have an entry that looks like:

:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/tools

Just look for the project in HEAD, this will also get you the sources, in case you want to debug...

Hope this helps,
Alex